# MVC 4 submit button on dialog Stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC4, VS2015, there is submit button on the dialog stopped working in production environment after 2 years, just does not do anything. No related code changes has been implemented for 3 month. The following function in js file is called from the View:

```
function ShowCommentsDialog(commentsDlg) {  
  var dlgId = "myDiv";
  appendDialog(dlgId, commentsDlg);

  $("#" + dlgId).dialog({
    buttons: {
      "Submit": function () {
        // update some elements with values
        $("#myField").val(my_text);
        $("#myForm").submit();
      },
      Cancel: function () {
        $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();      
      }
    },
    width: "auto"
  });
}
```

So `$("#myForm").submit()`  stopped working. So far this button

- did not work for 15-20 minutes when debugging locally, then started to work on first use of the button, not on second, then started to work consistently
- did not work for 15-20 minutes in QA environment, then started to work on first use of the button, not on second, then started to work consistently
- still does Not work in Production

When debugging locally it seems Controller does Not get any request when button clicked. Local & QA environments use same database. QA environment became slower in few recent days. No errors in Dev Tools Console in Browser.

Any ideas on what might be going on are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Something must have changed somwehre. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: have the users disabled javascript in the browser.

Comment: Perhaps an update was made to jquery or jquery Dialog?

Comment: Thank you for comments.  "bilpor' - "Allow all sites to run javascript" is ON.  'sleeyuen' - if update was made it should affect all environments, but it is Not the case (my question has details on that), 'Rory ...' - I've mentioned that there is No errors in Console.   Any other ideas?